# DLL missing from 'self-contained' core deployment (asp net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, self-contained

I was under the impression self-contained core deployments came with everything they needed as part of the build/release, but I've shipped the contents of my release folder to the target environment and I get the following error:

**An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.AspNet'WebApi.Client', version: '5.2.6'
path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'**

I've tried adding the following attribute to the project XML but I still can't see that DLL in the release directory:

`<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>`

Just to be clear, I've tried running the exe (which is when I get this error) from the publish directory and the winx64 directory (which I'm surprised to find is a lot smaller in size?)

I know probably one of the solutions here would be to ensure I install a framework/dependency on the target environment, but I really want to avoid doing that since I'd like this app to be truly self-contained.

Project XML:

[image]

Publish settings:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a package reference to that in your csproj?

Comment: @ChrisPratt - I have a dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.App which then references the WebApi.Client library. That's under 'SDK', I don't have a NuGet reference on it or anything.

Comment: can you show how is your reference made ? just a part of .csproj

Comment: so your application run successfully if you use the non self contained deploy?

Comment: It runs fine on my dev machine. On the target environment I get the same results whether from the self contained or framework dependent, and that is that it won't run because it's missing that DLL. I ideally want to avoid shipping this DLL separately or having to install it outside of my app, I want this app to be delivered in it's entirety (inc. supporting frameworks). Ideally.

Comment: But I don't see Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client among your references. Am I missing something?

Comment: AspNetCore.App references it

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Can you show your publish settings? Are you publishing it with self contained and non framework dependent settings?

Comment: What directory are you copying? Are you copying `Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/win-x64` or something else?

Comment: I've tried copying ever DIR that includes the exe, none of the exes run.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood - I'm publishing as self contained, I tried 'portable' but then switched to win 64, none of it's working.

Comment: Copy `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/win-x64/` and run the exe contained inside that on the target machine.

Comment: i tried that Omair it's still saying missing dll.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ - Please add a screenshot of your publish settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is related to using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage only.

> When you use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage, no assets from the referenced ASP.NET Core NuGet packages are deployed with the application—the ASP.NET Core shared framework contains these assets.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-2.2

It's not publishing any transient dependencies. But if you add the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` directly to your project, it should work properly.

Let me give you a simple example. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and will create simple console application.

**Example 1**

I've just created a fresh console application. The project file looks like that.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" />
    <!-- This is a metapackage ^^^ -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I publish the project, the output directory looks like that:

[image: Published console application with Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage only]

**Example 2**

Then I update the project by adding a reference to the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`. Now project file has an additional line:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.7" />
  <!-- Direct reference to the package ^^^ -->
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

There are transient dependencies for `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package are included.

[image: Published console application with direct reference to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client]

---

I hope it would help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vladimir! I rewarded the bounty as it was about to expire. I just tried this, but no additional DLLs were created in the publish folder. Which folder should I be looking at after publish? There are 390 files in the publish dir.

Comment: 390 files and no `Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll` and others?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Could you provide the simplest reproducible example of the project?